# The timing of defining new macro and reading its value from the aux file

Tags: macros, expl3, auxiliary-files

I would like to define two commands: `\RecordTagText{tag}{text}` which stores to each unique `tag` some `text`, and `\ShowTagText{list of tags}` which prints the `text` corresponding to the given list of tags, but **under the condition** that on each page the `text` for the same `tag` should only be printed once (thus if it is specified to be output twice, the second time should be ignored).

For this, my idea is to define `\RecordTagText` to simply write the tag/text information to the aux file, as follows:

```
\prop_new:N \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop
\NewDocumentCommand \RecordTagText { m m }
  {
    \iow_now:cn { @auxout }
      {
        \@RecordTagText { #1 } { #2 }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \@RecordTagText { m m }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  }
```

However, for `\ShowTagText`, I'm not sure what to do. My idea is to place a label for each `\ShowTagText` so as to access its page number, then for each tag `TAG` create a comma list `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _clist` to record the labels that use this tag, and then for each page number `xxx` and each tag `TAG` create a comma list `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _page_ xxx _clist` to record the labels that use this tag on page `xxx`, and finally based on these preparations to define `\ShowTagText`.

And this is where I'm getting confused. I have the following questions:

1. `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _clist` can only be determined after the first run, but where should I declare this clist via `\clist_new` in the first place?
2. `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _page_ xxx _clist` should be created based on `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _clist`, but I'm not sure at which stage can it obtain the value of `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _clist` (trying to output its value, I'm always getting the result `empty`).

Without being able to create `\g__mymodule_tag_ TAG _page_ xxx _clist` properly, I'm not sure what to do next, so my code just stops here. Below is my current code.

How should one properly define such two commands?
(Perhaps you have a better idea than the one I described above, if so, please kindly tell me.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% get the total page number
\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument } { mymodule }
  {
    \label{mymodule_last-page}
  }
\int_new:N \g_mymodule_total_page_int
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { mymodule }
  {
    \int_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_total_page_int { \getpagerefnumber{mymodule_last-page} }
  }

\prop_new:N \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop
\NewDocumentCommand \RecordTagText { m m }
  {
    \iow_now:cn { @auxout }
      {
        \@RecordTagText { #1 } { #2 }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \@RecordTagText { m m }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\newcounter{show-tag}
\int_new:N \g__mymodule_show_tag_counter_int
\NewDocumentCommand \ShowTagText { m }
  {
    \int_gdecr:N \g__mymodule_show_tag_counter_int
    \addtocounter { show-tag } { -1 }
    \refstepcounter { show-tag }
    \label { show-tag- \int_eval:n { \g__mymodule_show_tag_counter_int } }
    % for each tag, record the labels that use it
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \clist_gput_right:ce { g__mymodule_tag_ ##1 _clist } { \int_eval:n { \g__mymodule_show_tag_counter_int } }
      }
    %% What next?
    % \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    %   {
    %     \par
    %     \prop_item:Nn \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop { ##1 }
    %     \par
    %   }
  }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { mymodule/tag }
  {
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g__mymodule_tag_text_prop
      {
        % generate the list of label numbers that use the given tag
        \clist_new:c { g__mymodule_tag_ #1 _clist }
        \int_step_inline:nn { \int_eval:n { \g_mymodule_total_page_int } }
          {
            % generate the per page tag-label clist
            \clist_new:c { g__mymodule_tag_ #1 _page_ ##1 _clist }
            %% What next?
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag3}
\clearpage
\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag4}

\RecordTagText{tag1}{Text for TAG1.}
\RecordTagText{tag2}{Text for TAG2.}
\RecordTagText{tag3}{Text for TAG3.}
\RecordTagText{tag4}{Text for TAG4.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "but under the condition that on each page the text for the same tag should only be printed once (thus if it is specified to be output twice, the second time should be ignored)." it would be easier to always write, as you don't know the pagination at the time of writing but you can write the page number as an argument. When reading in the aux file on the next run it is trivial to make  `\@RecordTagText` ignore a second setting for the same page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I don't quite get your idea. To my understanding `\RecordTagText` does not care about the page number, since in principle you could write it anywhere in the document, only `\ShowTagText` cares about current page number and actually makes the output. Also, though I didn't stated in my question, this is actually part of a problem that deals with footnotes, so to make sure that the marker list in the footnote is correct, I kind of need to know, for each tag, and for each page, which are the labels referring to it.

Comment: yes but you don't know the page when you make the write but it is delayed until the page is known, however at that stage you can not not write the second ome so I would always write `\@recordText{key}{value}{page}`  then when reading it back if you have already seen a setting for this key on this page, ignore the value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see, you are right, and with this I don't even need to use so many auxiliary macros. I shall try if I could make this work :-)

Comment: How to handle the case of a snippet of text associated to a tag breaking across pages when referenced? Shall with all pages, where parts of the snippet of text occur, be assumed that there is no need to repeat the entire snippet?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I didn't really consider such situation. Since the actual object I am treating is footnote, I would say that when such thing happens, one should really switch to use endnote instead of footnote...

Comment: @Jinwen Now I found your reply to David Catlisle's comment. I did not yet read all your comments when asking this.Sorry.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Don't mind. I think you made a valid point. I shall add this to the "Known issues" section of the package `multifootnote`.

Comment: @Jinwen It's pretty common for footnotes to break across pages ;).

Comment: @cfr You are right, that is why I have kept a manual mode in the updated `multifootnote` package so that users can handle such situations themselves when necessary. However, if the footnotes are long enough so that breaking across pages become even necessary, using endnote instead of footnote seems to be a more natural solution, as is the case in many history books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call the attempt of writing a phrase of text that is associated to a tag a "tag-call".

Seems, the command `\ShowTagText{<list of tags>}` shall do a sequence of tag-calls.

In case

- you have a most recent LaTeX 2ε with ltproperties.dtx incorporated and
- you don't mind compiling the document at least three(!) times,

you can try s.th. like this:

Count via an integer-variable `\g_mymodule_tagcalls_int` the recording of absolute page-numbers due to tag-calls.

Have `\ShowTagText` map on the comma-list provided as `<list of tags>` a function `\mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n{<tag>}` which does the following things:

% Record absolute page-number and tag at the start of the tag-phrase:

- Globally increment `\g_mymodule_tagcalls_int` .
- Record the current absolute page number to a label `mymodule.tag.calls.(<value of \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int>)`.
- Record the tag-call to the .aux-file by writing a label of name `mymodule.tag.calls.(<value of \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int>)(<current absolute page number>)` with the value of a property `mymodule-tag` denoting the name of the `<tag>` to be shown.

% Check if another reference to this tag already occurred on the page, if not, then reference the tag:

- If the `<tag>` is not defined:
  Attempt to reference the tag in order to get `??` and warnings.
  Otherwise:
  Loop until the label `mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)` is undefined or the label `mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)` is defined to yield `<tag>`, in each iteration of the loop (locally) decrementing `<tag-call-number>`.
  If the case of the label `mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)` being defined to yield `<tag>` did not occur, then do a reference to the `<tag>`.

% Record absolute page-number and tag at the end of the tag-phrase:

- Globally increment `\g_mymodule_tagcalls_int` .
- Record the current absolute page number to a label `mymodule.tag.calls.(<value of \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int>)`.
- Record the tag-call to the .aux-file by writing a label of name `mymodule.tag.calls.(<value of \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int>)(<current absolute page number>)`  with the value of a property `mymodule-tag` denoting the name of the `<tag>` to be shown.

```latex
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
%=======================================================================
% Let's have a token-list-variable which holds the text associated to a
% tag:
%.......................................................................
\tl_new:N \g_mymodule_tag_text_tl 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's have a string-variable which holds characters denoting a tag:
%.......................................................................
\str_new:N \g_mymodule_tag_str
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's have a property "mymodule-tag-text":
%.......................................................................
\property_new:nnnn {mymodule-tag-text} 
                   {now} 
                   {\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}
                   {\tl_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_text_tl}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's have \RecordTagText{<tag>}{<text>} write a label 
% "mymodule.recorded-tags.<tag>" with property "mymodule-tag-text"
%  whose value is <text>:
%.......................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \RecordTagText #1 #2 
  {
    \@bsphack
    \str_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_tag_str {#1}
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_tag_text_tl {#2} 
    \exp_args:Ne
    \property_record:nn 
      {mymodule.recorded-tags.\str_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_str}
      {mymodule-tag-text}
    \@esphack
  }
%=======================================================================
% Let's call the attempt of writing a phrase of text that is associated
% to a tag a "tag-call".
%
% Seems, the command \ShowTagText{<list of tags>} shall do a sequence of
% tag-calls.
%
% This can be done by mapping on the comma-list provided as
% <list of tags>, passing each element to a function
% \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n .
%.......................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ShowTagText #1
  {
    \bool_gset_false:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n
  }
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's have a conditional denotimg whether \ShowTagText is referencing
% the first element of its list.
%.......................................................................
\bool_new:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% As checking on the presence of tags in property-values of
% referencing-labels needs to be done, let's have a property
% "mymodule-tag" 
% whose value is to come from a string-variable \g_mymodule_tag_str,
% which in turn is to hold the characters that make up the tag.
%.......................................................................
\property_new:nnnn {mymodule-tag}{now}{}
                   {\str_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_str}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Using the integer \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int for counting the recording
% of absolute page numbers due to \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n:
%.......................................................................
\int_new:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n {<tag>}
%
% With each tag-call do:
% - Set the value of \g_mymodule_tag_str to <tag>.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% - Globally _increment_ \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int.
% - Record the <current absolute page number> as label of name
%   "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)".
% - Record the tag-call to the .aux-file with writing at shipout-time
%   as label of name
%   "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)"
%   with value of property "<mymodule-tag> denoting <tag>".
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% - If the <tag> is not defined: 
%      Reference the tag to get `??` and warning-messages.
%   Otherwise:
%     Loop until the label 
%     "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)"
%     is undefined or the label 
%     "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)"
%     is defined to yield <tag>, in each iteration locally and expandably 
%     decrementing <tag-call-number>/in each iteration as <tag-call-number>
%     providing a set of tokens denoting a <number> where the value is
%     decremented.
%     If during the loop the case of a label 
%     "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)"
%     being defined to yield <tag> did not occur, then do
%     \property_ref:nn {mymodule.recorded-tags.\str_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_str} {mymodule-tag-text}.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% - Globally _increment_ \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int.
% - Record the <current absolute page number> as label of name
%   "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)".
% - Record the tag-call to the .aux-file with writing at shipout-time
%   as label of name
%   "mymodule.tag.calls.(<tag-call-number>)(<current absolute page number>)"
%   with value of property "<mymodule-tag> denoting <tag>".
%.......................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n
  {
    \str_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_tag_str {#1}
    %
    \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_writenextlabel:
    %
    \exp_args:Ne
    \property_if_recorded:nnTF {mymodule.recorded-tags.\str_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_str} {mymodule-tag-text}
    {
      \exp_args:Nf \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_loop:nn { \int_eval:n {\g_mymodule_tagcalls_int-1} }{#1}
    }
    {\use:n}
    {  
      \bool_if:NTF \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool {~} {\bool_gset_true:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool}
      \exp_args:Ne 
      \property_ref:nn {mymodule.recorded-tags.\str_use:N \g_mymodule_tag_str} {mymodule-tag-text}
    }
    % -----------------------------------------------------
    % In case you wish the tag-text to be repeatable on
    % the subsequent page when it was broken across pages
    % with the following lines swap the commenting:
    % -----------------------------------------------------
    \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_writenextlabel:
  }
\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_loop:nn
  {
    \exp_args:Ne
    \property_if_recorded:nnTF{mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}
    {
      \exp_args:Ne
      \property_if_recorded:nTF {
        mymodule.tag.calls.(#1)(
          \exp_args:Ne\property_ref:nn{mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}
       )
      }
      {
        \str_if_eq:eeTF
          { #2 }
          { 
            \exp_args:Ne
            \property_ref:nn{
              mymodule.tag.calls.(#1)(
                \exp_args:Ne \property_ref:nn{mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}
              )
            }{mymodule-tag}
          }
          { \use_none:n }
          { \exp_args:Nf \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_loop:nn { \int_eval:n {#1-1} }{#2} }
      }{
        \use:n
      }
    }{
      \use:n
    }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag_writenextlabel:
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int
    \exp_args:Ne
    \property_record:nn {mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}
    \exp_args:Ne
    \property_if_recorded:nnTF{mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}{
      \exp_args:Ne
      \property_record:nn {mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)(
        \exp_args:Ne
        \property_ref:nn {mymodule.tag.calls.(\int_use:N \g_mymodule_tagcalls_int)}{abspage}
      )}{mymodule-tag}
    }{}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag3}
\clearpage
\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag4}

% Within the 2nd argument of \RecordTagText don't insert material that yields
% breakpoints at the begin and/or at the end of the text denoted by the tag.
\RecordTagText{tag1}{Text for TAG1.}
\RecordTagText{tag2}{Text for TAG2.}
\RecordTagText{tag3}{Text for TAG3.}
\RecordTagText{tag4}{Text for TAG4.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nicely explained answer! And it is glad to see an example of how the new `ltproperties` system is used in action. Regarding the compilation times, I'm not quite sure, but I think that with the method mentioned in David Carlisle's comment, two compilations would be suffice (I haven't yet write the code directly for this question since after reading his comment I immediately went to edit the second method of `multifootnote` and the result seemed to be successful). Later when I have some more time I shall try to organize my code into an answer.

Comment: But I shall mark your answer as the accepted one, which is a pleasure to read and think about, as is always with your writings ;)

Comment: @Jinwen To be honest, I did not yet grasp the idea of David Carlisle. Thank you for accepting my answer, but - probably I shouldn't mention it - one motivation for me to write it was distracting myself from headache, so the probability of there being better approaches to the matter is high. As soon as a better answer arrives, feel free to un-accept my answer and accept that one. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following approach does without ltproperties and can probably do with two LaTeX-runs, but it relies on the absolute page number being available via the integer-variable `\g_shipout_readonly_int` which was introduced with the new hook-system.

The heart of the mechanism is writing to the .aux-file calls to a macro

```
\TagCallDataRecord
    {⟨id of the instance of \ShowTagText that produced the record⟩}
    {⟨tag⟩}
    {⟨absolute page⟩}
    {⟨begin/end of tag-text⟩}
    {⟨id of the record⟩}
```

.

The `⟨id of the record⟩` is used as component of the name of a cross-referencing-label that is to be created via `\newlabel`. The purpose of creating that cross-referencing-label is obtaining warnings in case a `\TagCallDataRecord` has changed.

`\TagCallDataRecord` is carried out both when the .aux-file of the previous LaTeX-run is read at the begin of the LaTeX-run and when the .aux-file created anew during the current LaTeX-run is read at the end of the current LaTeX-run. At the end of the current LaTeX-run the macro `\@newl@bel` is let equal to `\@testdef`. This fact can be used for turning `\TagCallDataRecord` into a no-op at the end of the LaTeX run which triggers messages about the need to re-run LaTeX in case things changed between LaTeX-runs.

When the .aux-file of the previous LaTeX-run is read at the begin of the LaTeX-run, `\TagCallDataRecord` is used to create and maintain two kinds of sequences:

1. For each absolute page-number where referencing a tag occurs a sequence is created which holds the tags referenced on that page.
2. For each  instance of `\ShowTagText` a sequence is created  which holds the tags to be referenced by that instance.

The tag of the `\TagCallDataRecord` is added to the sequence which holds the tags referenced on the page only if that sequence does not already contain it.

The tag of the `\TagCallDataRecord` is added to the sequence which holds the tags to be referenced by that instance of `\ShowTagText` only in case both the sequence which holds the tags referenced on the page does not already contain it and the `\TagCallDataRecord` does not denote the end of a tag-text. The latter is only if you don't want tag-text repeated on the second page in case it broke across pages.

```latex
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
%===============================================================================
% Part 1: Interface for defining/recording and referencing tags
%===============================================================================
% \RecordTagText{<tag>}{<text>} write a `\newlabel`-entry 
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \RecordTagText #1 #2 
  {
    \@bsphack
    \iow_shipout:Nx \@auxout {
      \token_to_str:N \newlabel{\tl_to_str:e {#1}}{\tl_to_str:e {#2}}
    }
    \@esphack
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \RefTagText{<tag>}
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \RefTagText #1 { \exp_args:Nc \@setref{r@#1}\@empty{#1} }
%===============================================================================
% Part 2: Interface for referencing tags only once per page
%===============================================================================
% \TagCallDataRecord
%    {<id of the instance of \ShowTagText that produced the record>}
%    {<tag>}
%    {<abspage>}
%    {<begin/end>}
%    {<id of the record>}
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \TagCallDataRecord #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \exp_args:NNe \use:nn \mymodule_TagCallDataRecord_stringified:nnnnn 
                  {
                    {\tl_to_str:n{#1}}
                    {\tl_to_str:n{#2}}
                    {\tl_to_str:n{#3}}
                    {\tl_to_str:n{#4}}
                    {\tl_to_str:n{#5}}
                  }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_TagCallDataRecord_stringified:nnnnn
  {
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % The only purpose of this \newlabel is raising a message in case s.th. 
    % changes between LaTeX runs.
    % The only purpose of \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextRecords_int is providing a
    % primary key for the name of the label as the arguments of
    % \mymodule_TagCallDataRecord_stringified:nnnn are not suitable for forming
    % a primary key.
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \newlabel {mymodule_TagCall(#5)}{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
    %...........................................................................
    % When the aux-file created during the LaTeX-run is read at the end of the
    % LaTeX-run, \@newl@bel is set equal to \@testdef by the LaTeX 2e kernel.
    %...........................................................................
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF \@newl@bel \@testdef {
      \seq_if_exist:cF 
        {g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(#1)_seq}
        { \seq_clear_new:c {g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(#1)_seq} }
      \seq_if_exist:cF 
        {g_mymodule_tags_on_abspage_(#3)_seq}
        { \seq_clear_new:c {g_mymodule_tags_on_abspage_(#3)_seq} }
      \seq_if_in:cnF {g_mymodule_tags_on_abspage_(#3)_seq} {#2} {
        \seq_gput_right:cn {g_mymodule_tags_on_abspage_(#3)_seq} {#2}
        %.......................................................................
        % With the following \str_if_eq:nnF-comparison commented out, in
        % case the text associated to the tag was broken across pages, 
        % so that part of it is on the subsequent page, the tag-text will
        % not be repeated on that subsequent page.
        %.......................................................................
        %\str_if_eq:nnF {#4} {end} {
          \seq_gput_right:cn {g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(#1)_seq} {#2}
        %}
      }
    }
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { e }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \mymodule_write_tag_call:nn {<tag>}{<begin/end>}
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_write_tag_call:nn
  {
    \iow_shipout_x:Nx \@auxout {
      \token_to_str:N \TagCallDataRecord
      {\tl_to_str:e {\int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int}}
      {\tl_to_str:e {#1}}
      {\exp_not:n{\int_use:N \g_shipout_readonly_int}}
      {\tl_to_str:e {#2}}
      {\tl_to_str:e {\int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextRecords_int}}
    }
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \mymodule_refer_tag_call:n {<tag>}
%...............................................................................
\tl_new:N \g_mymodule_scratch_tl
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_refer_tag_call:n #1
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF
      {
        g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(
          \int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
        )_seq
      }
      {
        \seq_get:cN
          {
            g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(
              \int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
            )_seq
          }
          \g_mymodule_scratch_tl
        \exp_args:No
        \quark_if_no_value:nTF  
          { \g_mymodule_scratch_tl }
          { \use_none:n }
          { \str_if_eq:eeT { \tl_use:N \g_mymodule_scratch_tl }{ #1 }  }
      }
      {
        \use:n
      }
    {
      \seq_if_exist:cT
        {
          g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(
            \int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
          )_seq
        }
        {
          \seq_gpop:cN
            {
              g_mymodule_tags_per_call_id_(
                \int_use:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
              )_seq
            }
            \g_mymodule_scratch_tl
        }
      \bool_if:NTF \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool 
                   {~} 
                   {\bool_gset_true:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool}
      %.........................................................................
      % Do the reference - this actually is the only place where the interface
      % for defining/recording and referencing tags and the interface for
      % referencing tags only once per page come into touch:
      %.........................................................................
      \RefTagText{#1}
      %.........................................................................
    }
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's have a conditional denotimg whether \ShowTagText is referencing the
% first element of its list.
%...............................................................................
\bool_new:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n{<tag>}
%...............................................................................
\int_new:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
\int_new:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextRecords_int
\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n 
  {
    \int_gincr:N  \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextRecords_int
    \mymodule_write_tag_call:nn {#1}{begin}
    \mymodule_refer_tag_call:n {#1}
    \int_gincr:N  \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextRecords_int
    \mymodule_write_tag_call:nn {#1}{end}
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \ShowTagText{<tag list>}
%...............................................................................
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ShowTagText #1
  {
    \bool_gset_false:N \g_mymodule_tagtextseparator_bool
    \int_gincr:N \g_mymodule_ShowTagTextInstances_int
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \mymodule_Show_text_of_this_tag:n
  }
%===============================================================================
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag3,tag3}

\clearpage
\ShowTagText{tag1,tag2}
\ShowTagText{tag2,tag4}

% Within the 2nd argument of \RecordTagText don't insert material that yields
% breakpoints at the begin and/or at the end of the text denoted by the tag.
\RecordTagText{tag1}{Text for TAG1.}
\RecordTagText{tag2}{Text for TAG2.}
\RecordTagText{tag3}{Text for TAG3.}
\RecordTagText{tag4}{Text for TAG4.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are so productive! Please give me some time to read it... By the way, thanks for the trick `\@bsphack`/`\@esphack`, I didn't notice this yesterday, but now that I looked up their meaning, it seems that this is something that I should definitely add to my corresponding macros.